# Error when running query against a calculated SQL model from server script in AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

When trying to perform a query on a SQL calculated (Cloud SQL) model from server script, I get "Error: Unsupported datasource type: SQL" and it points to the line where I call `run()` on the query object.
I don't see anything in the documentation saying it's not possible to perform that kind of query (I'm not using the keywords property in the SQL query, it's only pure SQL with GROUP BY, LEFT JOIN, SORT BY...).

```
var moreRecentDocsQ = app.models.more_recent_docs.newQuery(); // `more_recent_docs` is a SQL calculated model
var moreRecentDocs = moreRecentDocsQ.run(); // this throws the error
```

From front-side, I'm able to retrieve the items of this calculated model without problems (using `app.datasources.more_recent_docs.load()`).

Anyone facing this issue ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently calculated SQL datasource can't be called from Server Script due to a bug. We'll work on the fix.

The only workaround to run arbitrary SQL I can think of is to use [Apps Script Jdbc service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Any idea when it'll be fixed ? And how can we be informed of the fix ?

Comment: We'll try to fix it within 2 weeks. I'll update this thread when fix is rolled out.

Comment: It's fixed. Please redeploy the app and try again.